# QT how to access inner elements of a json using QSettings

Tags: json, qt, qsettings

This is my first week using json. I currently have an assignment to read the settings from a json file using Qsettings and display them. I have succeeded in reading a very simple one level json but I am having trouble with more complex ones.

I have the following test json

```
{
 "title" : "sometitle",
 "aNumber" : 321,
 "stats": {
     "str": 34,
     "int": 56,
     "con": 22
 },
 "agentsArray": [{
     "ID": 570,
     "picture": "03803.png",
     "name": "Bob"
 }, 
 {
     "ID": 571,
     "picture": "02103.png",
     "name": "Tina"
 }]
}
```

I need to access the values of the nested object and array using QSettings. Displaying the value of title and aNumber has been easy and I can print the values inside stats from withing the readJson function. 
However I cannot seem to figure out how to access the values inside stats from main

Here is my code

main

```
bool readJsonFile(QIODevice &device, QSettings::SettingsMap &map);
bool writeJsonFile(QIODevice &device, const QSettings::SettingsMap &map);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

   //Declare new JSON format
   const QSettings::Format jsonFormat = QSettings::registerFormat("json", readJsonFile, writeJsonFile);

   //Set default format to not specify it each time
   QSettings::setDefaultFormat(jsonFormat);

   //Using specific file
   QSettings settings("../Desktop/test/exemplu.json", jsonFormat);

   //works for title and aNumber
   qDebug() << settings.value("stats/str","empty").toString();
   qDebug() << settings.value("stats.int","empty").toString();
   qDebug()<<  settings.value("stats.con", "empty").toString();


   return a.exec();
}
```

readJsonFile

```
bool readJsonFile(QIODevice &device, QSettings::SettingsMap &map)
{
   QJsonParseError error;

   QString string = device.readAll();


   QByteArray jsonBytes = string.toLocal8Bit();
   auto document = QJsonDocument::fromJson(jsonBytes);

   if(document.isNull()){
           qDebug()<<"JSON not found";
           exit(2);
    }
    if(!document.isObject()){
        qDebug()<<"JSON is not of type object";
        exit(3);
    }

    QJsonObject json_obj=document.object();

    if(document.isEmpty()){
        qDebug()<<"JSON gol";
        exit(4);
    }
    map = json_obj.toVariantMap();

   //parsing stats
   QVariantMap stat_map = map["stats"].toMap();
   QVariantList inv_list = map["agentsArray"].toList();
   QStringList key_list = stat_map.keys();
   for(int i=0; i < key_list.count(); ++i){
       QString key=key_list.at(i);
       auto stat_val = stat_map[key.toLocal8Bit()].toString();
       qDebug() << key << ": " << stat_val;    //displays the values from stats
   }


   return true;
}
```

I understand that the problem is that I am saving the entire thing to map before parsing the object and the array but I have no idea how to go about saving the values from stats and the array inside map.

The signature of readJsonFile cannot be changed, I have to use map and device.

Comment: Why it's required to use `QSettings` to read JSON data if there are dedicated classes for it? It looks odd.

Comment: This is just the task I was assigned.